# Kill method of process not working

Tags: c#, process, kill

I am trying to test the following code snippet.

```
        static void StartAndKill()
    {
        Process ieProc = Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "www.apress.com");
        Console.WriteLine("--> Hit enter to kill {0}\t", ieProc.ProcessName);
        Console.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ieProc.Id);
            ieProc.Kill();

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

This should kill the internet explorer window and close it. Instead I get an exception that says:

```
Cannot process request because the process (7256) has exited.
```

What is the logical explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The real reason why the process doesn't get killed is administrative privs on Windows 7 are not defaulted. If I open a command prompt by using "Run as administrator", the code does what it is supposed to do. I will move to close this question.

Thanks to all those who responded.

Comment: Check ShellShock's answer. I believe when you start you process as admin it had to start IE as admin - hence you get new instance of IE, instead of exisiting one.

Answer (score 2):

If the iexplore process is already running (check Task Manager), then Process.Start may use the existing process - but the process id you get back is not for this existing process, but a dummy process that starts and then exits. You could enumerate the existing iexplore processes and check their titles to find the correct one, and then get its process id and kill it.

Comment: Same goes for other "single instance" applications (when process starts and in some conditions redirects work to exisitng process, not neccessary single process). Note, that IE will not necessary open process per tab (depending on version), so killing it may be bad idea (and killing tab's process will simply trigger recovery of the tab without any visual effect).

Comment: What Alexei says here appears to be what is going on.